# Recover the $C_k$-action of a cyclic object as from the $S^1$-action on Hochschild chain

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, equivariant-cohomology, equivariant-homotopy

$\newcommand{\Fun}{\operatorname{Fun}}$Let $X\in\Fun(\Lambda^\mathrm{op}, \mathcal{C})$ be a cyclic object in the ($\infty$-)symmetric monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$, where $\Lambda$ is the cyclic category of Connes.

Then, there exists a functor $\Fun(\Lambda^\mathrm{op}, \mathcal{C}) \rightarrow \Fun(BS^1, \mathcal{C})$, whose underline object is given by $colim_{\Delta^\mathrm{op}} X$.

On one hand, there is a natural functor $\Fun(BS^1, \mathcal{C})\rightarrow \Fun(BC_k, \mathcal{C})$ given by restriction to cyclic subgroup $C_k\subset S^1$.

On the other hand, I might construction a functor by
$$\Fun(\Lambda^\mathrm{op}, \mathcal{C})\xrightarrow{sd_k} \Fun(\Lambda_k^\mathrm{op}, \mathcal{C})\rightarrow \Fun^{BC_k}(\Lambda_k^\mathrm{op}, \mathcal{C}^{BC_k}) \rightarrow \mathcal{C}^{BC_k}=\Fun(BC_k, \mathcal{C}),$$
where the first functor is edge subdivision, and the last is the evaluation at $0$ (or truncation whatever).

My first question I am not very sure is: Is the section functor well-defined?

Next, we assume further that all arrows of the diagram of $X$ are isomorphisms in $\mathcal{C}$, i.e. $X\in \Fun(\Lambda^\mathrm{op}, \mathcal{C})_\simeq \simeq \Fun(BS^1, \mathcal{C})$. Then are these two functor naturally equivalent?

My motivation is: if we take an algebraic object in $C$, such that $m: A\otimes A \rightarrow A$ is an isomorphism, for example $A$ is a field or something more advance. We take $X$ as the cyclic bar complex, then the result of the first functor is $HH(A)$; and the result of the second functor gives us the cyclic permutation on $A^{\otimes k}$.

In general, I should not expect they are isomorphic cyclic equivariantly, but we assume $m: A\otimes A \rightarrow A$ is an isomorphism, we should have $A^{\otimes k}\simeq A$ for all $k$. Then we can expect the cyclic permutation on $A^{\otimes k}$ comes from the restriction on $S^1$-action of $HH(A)$. I think this is true if we really working on chain complexes. But I am not sure  how to write a proof for general categories. Is this possible true, or any possible references?

Or, maybe go back to the question in title, how can we obtain the cyclic permutation on $A^{\otimes k}$ from the $S^1$-action of $HH(A)$.